# AWS API Gateway route based on query string parameter

Tags: amazon-web-services, routes, aws-api-gateway

Is it possible to have AWS's API gateway route based on query string parameters?

So for example:

```
api.com/stuff?version=1.0
```

will route to:

```
https://endpoint.com/mystuff
```

and

```
api.com/stuff?version=2.0
```

will route to:

```
https://endpoint.com:8080/mystuff
```

So far I haven't seen anything for this. I can send custom query string parameters along to my endpoints, but I don't seem to be able actually to do anything with them. If it's not possible, have requests been made for this? I can do this through lambda but I would really like to make sure this can't be done through AWS API Gateway first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot route based on your query parameters, ([but it is possible to do the other way around](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/integrating-api-with-aws-services-lambda.html#api-as-lambda-proxy-expose-get-method-with-path-parameters-to-call-lambda-function) although seems out of your interest).

You can pick "Use Lambda Proxy integration" option and in your method integration request.

Then, in your lambda you use

```
#python
event['queryStringParameters']
```

to access you query string parameters to do whatever you like.

Comment: Dang. Alright, then that's what I will have to do. Thanks for the link and example.

Answer (score 0):

No, unfortunately you cannot route the requests base on route parameters. I'll suggest to use the API Gateway stages instead. You can deploy multiple versions of the same API and differentiate them base on the root part of the path

```
https://domaincom/v1/....
https://domaincom/v2/...
```

Comment: Please share the documentation source on this to find more details. I assume: 
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/how-to-call-api.html 
and
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/set-up-stages.html