# API gateway: HTTP integration using query string parameter as path parameter?

Tags: aws-api-gateway

OK, I'm not sure my title makes sense, but hopefully this explanation will. I have created an API with the following POST methods:

https://www.example.com/methodA

https://www.example.com/methodB

https://www.example.com/methodC

I am happy with the back end and am now starting to write the front end. However, the no-code/low-code front end tool that I'm using only allows a limited number of API endpoints before requiring a paid tier subscription that I'm not yet ready for.

I would like to configure API gateway to route a request based on a query string parameter. For example:

https://www.example.com/router?route=methodA ==> https://www.example.com/methodA

So API gateway would accept that URL on the left with the 'route' query string parameter and proxy it to the URL on the right. And my app builder tool would see that all of my app's API calls go to a single endpoint (namely, [www.example.com/router](http://www.example.com/router)).

Can this be done? If so, how? I've been stymied in my attempts so far. Ideally, the 'cheat URL' and the destination URL would be in the same API Gateway but I can stand up another API Gateway with a different hostname or domain name mapping if need be.

I have no intention of making this a permanent solution; I want more time to try the app builder that I'm using to ensure it'll meet my other needs before committing to a paid subscription.

Comment: Is it a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52487210/aws-api-gateway-route-based-on-query-string-parameter?

Comment: Yes, it does appear to be the same question. I wonder if the answer has changed in the past 5 years...